# How Can I Interpret Quoted Wildcards

Tags: shell, scripting, quoting, wildcards

I am writing a shell script and I need to interpret quoted wildcards.

```bash
"R Programming*"
```

I do not want the `*` asterisk to be taken literally.
I want it to be interpreted as a wildcard.

```bash
"R Programming"*
```

Is there a `sed` command I can use to convert the first into the second? And I want it to work with any string.

Comment: Do you have a string in your code like `string="R programming*"`, or like `string='"R programming*"'`? I.e., do you need to process the string for quote removal too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you have a shell variable that contains `R programming*` and that you want it to expand to the filenames that start with `R programming` in the current working directory, in `zsh`, you'd use `$~string` to request the expansion be taken as a pattern and globbing be performed as a result:

```
string="R programming*"
print -rC1 -- $~string
```

(or `print -rC1 -- $~string(N)` to get no output instead of an error if there's no matching file).

In `bash` and all other Bourne-like shell globbing is done by default upon unquoted parameter expansion (!) as well as word splitting. Here since the space character is in the default value of `$IFS` that is used to perform the latter, that would result in `R programming*` to be split into `R` and `programming*` before globbing is performed. You can change the value of `$IFS` to avoid that:

```
string="R programming*"
IFS=
shopt -s failglob
printf '%s\n' $string
```

Or to get no output if there's no matching file:

```
string="R programming*"
println() {
  [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\n' "$@"
}
shopt -u failglob
shopt -s nullglob
IFS=
println $string
```

In POSIX sh,

```
string="R programming*"
IFS=
printf '%s\n' $string
```

With the caveat that if there's no matching file, you'll get `R programming*` as output (same as if there was one single file called `R programming*` literally, a misfeature inherited from the Bourne shell, and there's no standard equivalent to `bash`'s `failglob` or `nullglob`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solution. All of them worked for me, I used POSIX.